# How to build cmd for ftp.retrlines(cmd, callback) in python and where is the file downloaded?

Tags: python, windows, ftp, text-files

Examples/explanation of using ftp.retrlines() I've found are all like:
response = ftp.retrlines('RETR test.txt', myfile.write)
That is, you should know beforehand that on the server there is a text file with the name 'test.txt'. But in real life the file name is known only at runtime. Normally we cannot write the cmd as 'RETR test.txt'.

I tried with the following code:

```
..........................
files = []
ftp.dir(files.append)
for f in files:
    #print(f[59:])
    with open(f[59:], 'w') as local_file:
        response = ftp.retrlines(' RETR ' + f[59:], local_file.write)
        if response.startswith('226'):
            print('Transfer complete')
        else:
            print('Error')
.........................
```

I expect that this way I should be able to download all files in this directory on the server. But at runtime python reports always that the line "response = ......" is incorrect. If I use
response = ftp.retrlines('RETR test.txt', local_file.write) # test.txt exists really on the server
instead, the program runs without error. But on my local computer I cannot find the file thus downloaded with the name test.txt. I even add the path in open() as
open('C:\fichier\text\' + f[59:0], 'w')
and still I cannot find the file downloaded. I even suspect that f[59:] would contain a newline at the end and use f[59:].strip(), all in vain, I cannot find the file.

Comment: did you mean`[:59]` to get the _first_ part of the name? `[59:]` may be an empty string

Comment: I do mean f[59:] which I've verified with the print() function which is commented out in my code snippet. Please refer to the output of ls -l command in UNIX.

Comment: *"That the line ... is incorrect"* is pretty vague. You sure get more specific message. + We need [mcve]. + You seem to have two disctinct problems. Please ask them separatelly.